# active/active load balancer in linux?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy, keepalived

we have 2 haproxy servers in an active passive (keepalived) setup forwarding to a couple apache backends. The load has increased and I'm searching for an active active load balancer solution. Is there anybody that has faced a similar issue? If possible I would prefer not to mess around with the DNS setup.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If changing your DNS setup really isn't an option, you could setup another network and announce (via BGP) your address space in multiple locations. Of course this brings it's own additional challenges.

If you can change your DNS setup, setup another active/passive haproxy setup and round robin the requests.

Since you have the active/passive setup today, I assume that availability is important. Given that, what you do not want to do is decrease your resiliency by depending on an active/active pair where losing one would overload the other causing a cascading failure.

Answer (score 0):

Active/Active is very hard to achieve and as mentioned above - fairly pointless when it comes to high availability. Just use a bigger faster pair of load balancers and make sure you are using multiple-threads. HAProxy easily scales to 30Gb/s+ if you need more than that then you will need LVS/GSLB/BGP/Multicast.